# Simple list removal in python not working

Tags: python

Trying to remove a tuple from a list of tuples.  From the output it would seem like it can remove... yet instead it gives ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

```
oldPosition = 0
newPosition = 0
counter = -1
newPartition = copy.deepcopy(partitions)
# Find which cluster the current point is in and where the move-to cluster is
for clusters in partitions:
    counter += 1
    if (inCluster(point,clusters)):
        oldPosition = counter
    if (cluster == clusters):
        newPosition = counter

# Do the removal and appending
print "Old: " + str(oldPosition) + "New: " + str(newPosition)
print "Remove From =  " + str(newPartition[oldPosition])
print "Remove = " + str(point)
newPartition[oldPosition].remove(point)
```

Output is

```
Old: 1New: 0
Remove From =  [(2.64, 3.3, 5.24), (1.64, 1.2, 3.82), (3.59, 7.5, 6.58), (1.94, 5.6, 4.25), (3.09, 6.5, 5.87), (0.54, 4.6, 2.27), (2.04, 4.5, 4.39), (-0.16, 3.8, 1.28)]
Remove = (2.64, 3.3, 5.24)
```

But it says (2.64, 3.3, 5.24) is not in the list?

EDIT: Full code

```
# Return whether a point is in a cluster
def inCluster(point, cluster):
    for points in cluster:
        if (point == points):
            return True

    return False                    # Default return: will only reach here if no points match

# Given a cluster, return the coordinates corresponding to its center of gravity
def centerOfGravity(cluster):
    total = (0,0,0)
    count = 0
    for points in cluster:
        total = tuple(map(operator.add, total, points))
        count += 1
    return (total[0] / count, total[1] / count, total[2] / count)

# Returns new partition after moving specified point from its old cluster to the new cluster
def moveToNewCluster(point, cluster, partitions):
    oldPosition = 0
    newPosition = 0
    counter = -1
    newPartition = copy.deepcopy(partitions)
    # Find which cluster the current point is in and where the move-to cluster is
    for clusters in partitions:
        counter += 1
        if (inCluster(point,clusters)):
            oldPosition = counter
        if (cluster == clusters):
            newPosition = counter

    # Do the removal and appending
    print "Old: " + str(oldPosition) + "New: " + str(newPosition)
    print "Remove From =  " + str(newPartition[oldPosition])
    print "Remove = " + str(point)
    newPartition[oldPosition].remove(point)
    newPartition[newPosition].append(point)

    # Clean up the new partition (we created at most one empty partition)
    newPartition.remove([])

    return newPartition

# Return a list of centers of gravity given the new partitions
def allCentersOfGravity(partitions):
    partitionsCoG = []
    for clusters in partitions:
        partitionsCoG.append(centerOfGravity(clusters))
    return partitionsCoG

# Find the euclidean distance in 3 space between two points
def distance(a, b):
    return math.sqrt(pow(a[0]-b[0], 2) + pow(a[1]-b[1], 2) + pow(a[2]-b[2], 2))

# Find the smallest absolute value distance from a point to a center of gravity
def minCenterDistance(point, centerOfGravities):
    minimumDistance = 10000000000
    dist = 0
    for center in centerOfGravities:
        dist = abs(distance(point, center))
        if (dist < minimumDistance):
            minimumDistance = dist
    return minimumDistance

# Given a set of points and partitions of those points, calculate the suqard error distortion
def squaredErrorDistortion(points, centerOfGravities):
    total = 0
    for point in points:
        total += pow(minCenterDistance(point, centerOfGravities), 2)
    total = total / len(points)
    return total

# Calculate the cost of moving point into cluster
# Value of a move is calculated as the old squared error distortion minus the new squared eror distortion
def moveValue(point, cluster, partitions, points):
    # Create the new partition formed by the swap
    newPartition = moveToNewCluster(point, cluster, partitions)
    # Get the centers of gravity for the clusters
    oldCoG = allCentersOfGravity(partitions)
    newCoG = allCentersOfGravity(newPartition)

    oldError = squaredErrorDistortion(points, oldCoG)
    newError = squaredErrorDistortion(points, newCoG)

    print "Old Partition: " + str(partitions)
    print "Old CoG: " + str(oldCoG)
    print "Old Error: " + str(oldError)
    print "New Partition: " + str(newPartition)
    print "New CoG: " + str(newCoG)
    print "New Error: " + str(newError)

    # Define the value as old - new.  If expecting the other way around results could be different
    moveErrorValue = oldError - newError

    return moveErrorValue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # The points
    points = [(0.39, 3.3, 2.06), (0.09, 4.5, 1.63), (2.64, 3.3, 5.24), (1.64, 1.2, 3.82), (3.59, 7.5, 6.58),
              (1.94, 5.6, 4.25), (3.09, 6.5, 5.87), (0.54, 4.6, 2.27), (2.04, 4.5, 4.39), (-0.16, 3.8, 1.28)]

    # Initial Partition
    partitions = [[points[0], points[1]],
                  [points[2], points[3], points[4], points[5], points[6], points[7], points[8], points[9]]]
    '''
    # Center of Gravity test
    print centerOfGravity(partitions[0])

    # InCluster test
    print inCluster(points[0], partitions[1])
    print inCluster(points[0], partitions[0])
    '''
    # moveValue(points[2], partitions[0], partitions, points

    bestPartition = []
    tempPartition = copy.deepcopy(partitions)
    while (1==1):
        bestChangeValue = 0                                                                        # The higher the change value the better since we are doing old-new
        for cluster in tempPartition:
            for point in points:
                valueOfMove = moveValue(point, cluster, tempPartition, points)                 # Have to send partition over in order to find the cluster the point is currently in
                if (valueOfMove > bestChangeValue):
                    bestChangevalue = valueOfMove
                    bestPartition = moveToNewCluster(point, cluster, tempPartition)            # Create the new partition
        if (bestChangeValue > 0):
            tempPartition = bestPartition
        else:
            break
    # At the end, tempPartition holds the best k-means partition
    print "Best partition is: " + str(tempPartition)
    print "Error Value: " + str(squaredErrorDistortion(points, allCentersOfGravity(tempPartition)))
```

Comment: What is point? Note that floating points numbers can have precision issues, i.e. you *think* `point` is equal to the element of the list, but it actually isn't. Try to use `print "Remove = " + repr(point)` instead and see if the output changes.

Comment: How are you generating these tuples?

Comment: `l = [(2.64, 3.3, 5.24), (...` and then `l.remove((2.64, 3.3, 5.24))` works for me.

Comment: As @Bakuriu correctly points out, this might as well be a precision issue, the way to get around this would be to write a delta-compare function, that checks if `|x-y| < delta`, where delta is some small (very) number.

Comment: Let me post my entire code so you can see I guess.  The tupels are just being seeded into two groups of points at random and then are worked on progressively.  The stuff in the while loop hasn't been fully debugged since I haven't been able to run it with the remove working, although all of the other functions appear to be working so far...

Comment: The thing is I don't see how there would be a precision error since the points are not manipulated at all.  They are set once at the start then any operations on them go into a different list.  THe originals are left untouched.

Comment: small change, added check to make sure the current point we are interating through isn't in the cluster currently being iterated through, but the original example doesn't encounter that problem so that's not the source.

Comment: The exception says `newPartition.remove([]) ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. It's not about removing the point, but about removing the empty list.

Comment: Please, the next time paste the **full** traceback of the exception, do *not* just say "I got an error" or "I got `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`". Even better: before asking the question try to "strip down" your code to the minimum lines that gives the error. Most of the time before you reach this point you understand autonomously why the error was raised, otherwise your question will make the error more localized and therefore easier to reason about it for other people. Taking time writing good questions is a win-win situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is in this line

```
# Clean up the new partition (we created at most one empty partition)
newPartition.remove([])
```

There are no empty lists in `newPartition`. If you absolutely want to make sure, they are not there, you can do this

```
if [] in newPartition: newPartition.remove([])
```

With this change, your program runs without any problems.

Comment: Oh well that was a really dumb oversight haha.  Thanks.  Lots of code only to get tripped up by an accident non check lol.